# Getting code=OrganizationFromTenantGuidNotFound while updating group using Microsoft Graph

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am getting the below exception

"error": {
    "code": "OrganizationFromTenantGuidNotFound",
    "message": "The tenant for tenant guid '****' does not exist.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "2acd6af1-99f8-4aab-b71d-cffc60263a05",
      "date": "2019-04-20T11:33:04"
    }

while updating the group using open extension as shown below: -

POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/db5f4dbe-40e0-4352-84fb-9a20c131cfaf/extensions HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer ****
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Host: graph.microsoft.com
Content-Length: 111
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

{ "@odata.type":"microsoft.graph.openTypeExtension","extensionName":"com.test.nickName","date":"OpenExtension"}

I am using user***@outlook.com id and having active azure subscription. I have given all delegated permission to microsoft graph.

Comment: Looks like you're using a Microsoft Account `***@outlook.com` and the error is happening when trying to figure out the tenant.. Can you try using any organizational account instead (after giving them the relevant permissions)? like `***@yourADTenant.onmicrosoft.com` or `***@yourtenantverfieddomain.com`

Comment: Still same error. I tried using Admin@mytenant.onmicrosoft.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content type was not specified and it was going as text. Error handling could be improved. After changing content type to "application/json", it is working perfectly fine.

POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/db5f4dbe-40e0-4352-84fb-9a20c131cfaf/extensions HTTP/1.1 Authorization: Bearer **** Content-Type: **application/json**; charset=utf-8 Host: graph.microsoft.com Content-Length: 111 Expect: 100-continue Connection: Keep-Alive

{ "@odata.type":"microsoft.graph.openTypeExtension","extensionName":"com.test.nickName","date":"OpenExtension"}

Comment: Where did you change this type could you please share?

Comment: @You were tried on Postman or something like that right? Or on code?